# Comparing Coordinate Reference Systems in GeoTools

Tags: coordinate-system, geotools

This seems like a pretty silly problem. I'm using a Maven build with GeoTools 14.0. All I want is to compare CRSs with flexibility so that it doesn't have to be exactly equal as long as all the parameters are equal.

There's a method listed for that here: http://docs.geotools.org/stable/userguide/library/referencing/compare.html as `equals(CoordinateReferenceSystem, boolean)`

But it doesn't actually exist in the GeoTools library or API docs. What gives? What's the alternative besides manually doing it, which is doable but just seeing how convoluted/intricate the CRS structure is in GeoTools this seems like a lot of work that should be unnecessary for a major spatial library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it moved to the CRS utility class as [equalsIgnoreMetadata](http://docs.geotools.org/latest/javadocs/org/geotools/referencing/CRS.html#equalsIgnoreMetadata(java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object))